# WCF client to WSE 3.0 service

Tags: wcf, wse3.0

I try to create WCF client to WSE 3.0 service. I have already working WSE3.0 client to the same service. Here is it's configurations:

```
 <microsoft.web.services3>
  <security>
   <timeToleranceInSeconds value="10000"/>
   <x509 allowTestRoot="true" verifyTrust="true" storeLocation="CurrentUser"/>
   <binarySecurityTokenManager>
    <add valueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">
     <keyAlgorithm name="RSA15"/>
    </add>
   </binarySecurityTokenManager>
  </security>
 </microsoft.web.services3>
```

And the policy for the service client created in such a way:

```
  MutualCertificate10Assertion assertion = new MutualCertificate10Assertion()
  {
    EstablishSecurityContext = false,
    RenewExpiredSecurityContext = true,
    RequireSignatureConfirmation = false,
    MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt,
    RequireDerivedKeys = false,
    TtlInSeconds = 300
  };

  assertion.ClientX509TokenProvider = new X509TokenProvider(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, "ClientCerfiticateName", X509FindType.FindBySubjectName);
  assertion.ServiceX509TokenProvider = new X509TokenProvider(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, "ServiceCerfiticateName", X509FindType.FindBySubjectName);

  //protection
    assertion.Protection.Request.SignatureOptions = SignatureOptions.IncludeAddressing | SignatureOptions.IncludeTimestamp | SignatureOptions.IncludeSoapBody;
    assertion.Protection.Request.EncryptBody = true;

    assertion.Protection.Response.SignatureOptions = SignatureOptions.IncludeAddressing | SignatureOptions.IncludeTimestamp | SignatureOptions.IncludeSoapBody;
    assertion.Protection.Response.EncryptBody = true;

    assertion.Protection.Fault.SignatureOptions = SignatureOptions.IncludeAddressing | SignatureOptions.IncludeTimestamp | SignatureOptions.IncludeSoapBody;
    assertion.Protection.Fault.EncryptBody = false;

  this.Policy = new Policy(new TraceAssertion(serviceUri), assertion, new RequireActionHeaderAssertion());
```

Now I try to use it to create WCF client. I used these recommendations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730299.aspx). I generated types form the service and the client contract, then created WseHttpBinding class derived from Binding, after that I tried to create this custom binding and initialize client and service certificates:

```
 string clientCertificateName = "ClientCertificateName";
 string serviceCertificateName = "ServiceCertificateName";

 Uri uri = new Uri("http://WantedService.asmx"));

  EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(uri,
                         EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(serviceCertificateName ));

  WseHttpBinding binding = new WseHttpBinding()
  {
    SecurityAssertion = WseSecurityAssertion.MutualCertificate10,
    EstablishSecurityContext = false,
    RequireSignatureConfirmation = false,
    MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt,
    RequireDerivedKeys = false
  };

  WantedServiceClient client = new CreativeGroupCurrencyServiceClient(binding, address);

// Set up certificates      
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetScopedCertificate(
                             StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                             StoreName.My,
                             X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                             serviceCertificateName , 
                            uri);

  client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                             StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                             StoreName.My,
                             X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                             clientCertificateName);

  WantedMethodResponse response = client.WantedMethod(new GetCurrenciesRequest());
```

But an exception occurred:

> System.Xml.XmlException: Cannot read
>   the token from the
>   'SignatureConfirmation' element with
>   the
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd'
>   namespace for
>   BinarySecretSecurityToken, with a ''
>   ValueType. If this element is expected
>   to be valid, ensure that security is
>   configured to consume tokens with the
>   name, namespace and value type
>   specified.

Why does not it work? And why the scheme is 1.1? Should I use WS Secure 1.1 in at MessageSecurityVersion for secure binding element? And which one? I tried this:

```
  WseHttpBinding binding = new WseHttpBinding()
  {
    SecurityAssertion = WseSecurityAssertion.MutualCertificate11,
    ...
  };
```

Which one uses WS Security 1.1 - `MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11` (while configuring in WseHttpBinding) but it failed also:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
>   Signature confirmation is not expected
>   in the security header.

I don't know what could I even do now! It seems I tried everything!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2007/07/18/interoperability-between-wcf-and-wse-3-0.aspx) article there is an error in the msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730049.aspx) on wcf wse compatibility. Specifically with respect to the message versions. This could be what is causing you problems.